# HDMI sound output not coming

Tags: debian, ubuntu, audio, hdmi, devuan

I'm on Dell Latitude 3420; it came with pre-installed Ubuntu 20.04.

I am dual booting with Devuan Chimeara

**uname -a**

```
Linux devuan-Latitude 5.10.0-22-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.178-3 (2023-04-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am able to connect to the external TV display; but no sound in the external TV display.

The HDMI sound output works fine with Ubuntu 20.04.7, but not with Devuan.

[image: This is the pavucontrol dialog in Devuan]

Earlier, there was no sound output even through the internal speakers. But that was resolved after installing `firmware-sof-signed`

**Ubuntu info:**

uname -a

```
Linux Latitude-3420 5.14.0-1032-oem #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 31 12:49:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following config change in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` (at the end of this file) did the trick:

```
 snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

So, the HDMI sound output is solved. Hurray!!
Thanks to the guys at [Official Devuan Forum](https://dev1galaxy.org), especially **delgado**.